# Cross-Platform JSON Serialization

Tags: java, c#, json, serialization

I'm looking to share object data between two independent desktop applications. Normally, I would use a Serialization Library to serialize objects in one app, and then Deserialize them in the other app (and casting the data to an object).

**The Problem:**

- I'm serializing objects in C#
- I **want** to deserialize them in Java

**Example**

Here is a c# class (Foo) that I want to deserialize in Java:

```
class Foo
{
    public List<Bar> BarList {get;set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
class Bar
{
    public string X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
}
```

Note: I'm using [JSON.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to serialize

**JSON for an example Foo Object**

> {
>     "BarList": [
>       {
>         "X": "hi",
>         "Y": 5
>       },
>       {
>         "X": "hello",
>         "Y": 10
>       }
>     ],
>     "Name": "foo"
>   }

**Consuming this object in Java**

Let's assume I have a very similar Foo class in Java. Instead of Properties, it has standard private members with public getter/setter methods.

Now, I could simply do something like:

```
class Foo
{
    private ArrayList<Bar> barList;
    private string name;

    public Foo(string pathToJsonFile)
    {
         // Method/Code to manually grab the needed JSON and call setters
    }

    // Setters/Getters
}
```

This solution works, but I would rather avoid having this constructor on every single object in my Java project. Plus, if I have deeply coupled objects, this method would be huge (deserialize this object, but it contains objects that also need deserialized, etc, etc).

**My Question:**

Are there any Deserialization methods that are in the **Java Standard Library**, that could make this process easier?

Algorithm ideas would also be appreciated (I don't mind creating a small framework).

Third-party solutions are okay, as long as they are completely **open-source, with no .jar dependencies**.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [JSON-B](http://json-b.net/index.html) (JSR 367)?  Although this does not appear to be in the standard library yet, the final spec [was approved](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/results?id=6007) in June of this year.  There is an official reference implementation called [Yasson](https://github.com/eclipse/yasson) that is open source.

If that is not what you are looking for, there are all kinds of third-party open source libraries which handle JSON binding in Java, such as [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson), [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson), [Genson](https://github.com/owlike/genson), [FlexJson](http://flexjson.sourceforge.net/) and [json-simple](https://code.google.com/archive/p/json-simple/) to name just a few.  Of those, the first two seem to be the most popular.  You can find even more libraries listed on [json.org](http://www.json.org/).

Comment: Do you know offhand if this implementation works with objects whose source is inaccessible (like an object from a .jar reference)?

Comment: I do not know offhand; you'd have to look a the spec.  I think Gson supports that however.

Answer (score 0):

Last time I checked, Java SE had none of that. In Java EE, there is API in package `java.ws.rs`, at least. You could use the API and be pretty much independent on the implementation.

If you want to create your own framework, have fun. JSON is a lot more complex than you might think, so depending on how big subset of it you want to support, this task could be quite time-consuming.

Comment: I'm not looking for a solution that can work with literally any object. Google GSON is actually quite good with that (but it has .jar dependencies). I think if I broke down the work enough, making my own deserialization framework for under 20 classes shouldn't be that bad.

Comment: I don't think it's a big deal if all you need is the subset that you are currently using. Not sure what is the deal, why you can't use third party libraries, but gl&hf.

Comment: The code runs from source files, remotely. Can't run code from .jars. I might be able to do GSON, but last time I tried there were some references to .jar files. Might be different (or fixable) now.